# Смена CSS через JS с задержкой после загрузки страницы

Tags: javascript

Как с помощью javascript изменить стиль блока `<div>` c `opacity: 0` на `opacity: 1` через 10 секунд после загрузки страницы?

Comment: Вопрос распадается на два независимых: как изменить стиль блока и икак сделать что-то через N секунд после загрузки страницы. Непонятно, что из этого вы не смогли сделать самостоятельно. В любом случае **эти два вопроса стоит опубликовать раздельно**.

Comment: Отметьте вопрос как принятый (зелёная галочка слева от ответа), так как я понимаю, что он вам помог.

Comment: Не согласен с текущими причинами закрытия: "невозможно дать лаконичный ответ" (прям невозможно никак:)) и вообще с закрытием этого вопроса. Да, он простой, но он ИМХО имеет право на существование.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: в ответе выше идет замена через "setTimeout" с задержкой в 10 сек.
А как именно сделать, после загрузки страницы?

Comment: @TarakaN27 Можно конечно и setTimeout, но я бы  sleep  сделал, удобнее и проще, но это асинхронность. setTimeout кстати тоже

Comment: await sleep(10000) ; element.style.opacity = 0.5;

Answer (score 7):

[Таймеры.](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval)
[Изменить CSS-свойство.](https://a-panov.ru/css-using-js/)

```js
// Создаём функцию, которая запустится при загрузке страницы
(function() {
  // Создаём таймер
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector('span').style.opacity = '1'; // Меняем прозрачность
  }, 10000); // 10000 мсек = 10 сек
})();
```

```css
span {opacity: 0}
```

```html
<span>Текст</span>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, весь интернет облазил и ничего не нашёл.

Comment: @Other, давайте продолжим в моём чате: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52027/communication-with-the-yuri